# Outer Join 2 Data Frames in R two columns to one

Tags: r, merge

I am SURE that this is answered somewhere but I just don't know what this kind of operation is called to research.  I have two tables:

Score:

| Name | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 14 |
| Janet | 8 |
| Fred | 87 |
| Alex | 221 |

Schedule:

| Left Player | Right Player |
| --- | --- |
| Janet | Fred |
| Alex | Bob |

So, I have a few things I want to do with this, but the main part I'm stuck on is if I want to make a new column in the "Score" table that is "Next Opponent".  And it looks through the "Schedule" table and sees if the player is the left player and if they are fills in the right player as Next Opponent, and then does the reverse if they are the Right Player. I'm happy to research this on my own, I just don't know what this kind of merge is called or if this is a set of iteration with if statements or not.  Would love a bump in the right direction here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest reconfiguring `Schedule` as a table with `Name` and `Opponent` columns. Then it's just a left join.

```
library(dplyr)

Matchups <- bind_rows(
  Schedule %>% transmute(Name = Left.Player, Opponent = Right.Player),
  Schedule %>% transmute(Name = Right.Player, Opponent = Left.Player)
)

left_join(Score, Matchups)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "Name"
   Name Points Opponent
1   Bob     14     Alex
2 Janet      8     Fred
3  Fred     87    Janet
4  Alex    221      Bob
```

Or alternatively:

```
Score %>%
  left_join(Schedule, by = c("Name" = "Left.Player")) %>%
  left_join(Schedule, by = c("Name" = "Right.Player")) %>%
  mutate(Opponent = coalesce(Left.Player, Right.Player))


   Name Points Right.Player Left.Player Opponent
1   Bob     14         <NA>        Alex     Alex
2 Janet      8         Fred        <NA>     Fred
3  Fred     87         <NA>       Janet    Janet
4  Alex    221          Bob        <NA>      Bob
```

Comment: Delightful, thank you for the assistance.